# Should I use Linq-to-SQL or the Castle ActiveRecord implementation?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-sql, castle-activerecord

I don't want to write stored procedures any more (not unless I have to), so should I use out of the box [Linq-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) or the [Castle ActiveRecord implementation](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html)?

I understand there are some differences between the two as mentioned [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984844/does-linq-to-sql-use-the-activerecord-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you happen to be choosing between those two only?

LinqToSql currently has a better Linq provider than NHibernate.

Castle ActiveRecord is based on NHibernate.  NHibernate is a lot more feature rich than LinqToSql and features are being added much more quickly to NHibernate.

Depending on the complexity of your domain, data model, and requirements, you may be forced to go with NHibernate at some point because LinqToSql just can't do what you need it to do (you haven't specified what kind of environment and requirements you have, which makes a big difference).

It can be difficult/expensive to transition from one ORM to another, so it is important to choose wisely.

There are some situations where I would recommend LinqToSql over Castle ActiveRecord, but they are few and far between.  Generally, Castle ActiveRecord is much more likely to work in your situation.

Comment: The targetted apps are usually enterprise-wide systems that are built with ASP.NET. We're moving from 2.0 to 3.5 and have been using a traditional DAL built using ADO.NET. We need to move away from that.

Comment: @Naeem: I would start with Castle ActiveRecord if I were you.

Answer (score 3):

I would say try both, and see which suits your needs best. Asking questions like these you will most likely get another answer - "which one I like better". There's no one size fits all solution, and with little details you have given it's hard to help you really.

Notice that ActiveRecord uses NHibernate underneath, which is a much more powerful ORM than L2S, so if you intend your project to grow, it's flexibility and maturity may be helpful in the long run.

Comment: We've tried a couple of projects using L2SQL but no one wants to give AR a go because we still have to write "code" to mark up our database tables & relations.

Comment: I'm not 100% what you mean by that. You'll end up writing more code to deal with Linq to SQL in the long run because with AR (NHibernate underneath it) you can bend your entities to be almost anything you need them to be for your model. L2S maps clasess to tables 1-1 so you'll have to map and convert them later on, which means more code you have to write.

Comment: @Naeem: Which code generators have you tried for Castle ActiveRecord?

Comment: @Michael, sorry I wasn't clear. We haven't tried Active Record seriously yet. I've coded up a couple of tables just to get started but I never got further than that.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq to SQL - its very easy to get started and there is a lot of documentation out there for it. In addition you don't need to take any dependencies on anything outside the box, which will save you time.

Comment: The designer seems to make it easy to get started too, whereas I'll need to code up all my classes with Castle AR.

Comment: Not really. There's a designer for ActiveRecord called ActiveWriter. It is not recommended to use a designer in a real project though

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic - What's a 'real' project?

Comment: Designers tend not to scale well as the number of tables grow and they tend not to support edge cases very well, and edge cases are all too common in reality.  LinqToSql's designer has its own set of troublesome issues, like not being able to easily sync up with changes in the database.

Comment: @Naeem: Castle AR supports the same sort of designers and code generation that LinqToSql supports.  You are certainly welcome to code up your classes, but that's a choice, not a requirement.

Comment: When the db schema changes I regenerate the dbml file and run a transformation script against it rather than make changes with the designer. Or at least I did until I learnt NH.

Comment: @Paddy

Try to use a designer when you have 100 big tables, or even 50.
Try to use it with version control...

Answer (score 0):

Linq-to-SQL seems to be loosing ground due to Entity Framework. Since EF integrates nicely with many new and upcoming MS technologies, you probably would not regret using EF. Not sure how it fares in comparison with Casle thuogh.

Comment: EF has a number of very annoying parts in the current incarnation.